# show prompt while the user cancels, it gets uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have declared a function called `init()`, it ask the users the game size, which is separated by the space. I want to show the prompt while the user doesn't click on `ok` and acts like cancel (explicitly click on the cancel or implicitly press the `esc` keyboard).

Here is what I have implemented:

```
function init(){
    let promptMessage = 'تعداد سطرها و ستون‌های جدول را به ترتیب وارد کرده و با فاصله از هم جدا کنید\nمثلا مقدار پیش‌فرض دارای 7 جدول و 6 ستون است';
    let promptDefault = '7 6';
    let prompt = this.prompt(promptMessage, promptDefault);
    if (prompt) {
        prompt = prompt.split(" ")
        console.log(prompt);
        prompt[0] = Number(prompt[0]);
        prompt[1] = Number(prompt[1]);
        return prompt;
    }
    init()
}

var gameSize = init(),
    rows = gameSize[0],
    cols = gameSize[1];
```

When I test the above code, after I click on the cancel, it works correctly and show the prompt again but the problem is that it gives me the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in line `rows = gameSize[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `gameSize = init()` it runs the init() function and if the user hits cancel the function will return `undefined` because you do not declare a `return` statement in that code path.

Then when you do `var rows = gameSize[0]`, `gameSize` is `undefined` at that point and results in the error you see.

What you need to do is return the result from the next call of `init()`.

```js
function init(){
    let promptMessage = 'تعداد سطرها و ستون‌های جدول را به ترتیب وارد کرده و با فاصله از هم جدا کنید\nمثلا مقدار پیش‌فرض دارای 7 جدول و 6 ستون است';
    let promptDefault = '7 6';
    let prompt = this.prompt(promptMessage, promptDefault);
    if (prompt) {
        prompt = prompt.split(" ")
        console.log(prompt);
        prompt[0] = Number(prompt[0]);
        prompt[1] = Number(prompt[1]);
        return prompt;
    }
    return init();
}

var gameSize = init(),
    rows = gameSize[0],
    cols = gameSize[1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because gameSize is not yet defined when you try to access it.
Try to declare gameSize variable before rows and cols

```
var gameSize = init();
var rows = gameSize[0],
    cols = gameSize[1];
```